# Is it considered fair to recommend that people upvote an answer if they feel it is worth it?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes

I have been after the elusive Populist badge for a long time. It has been almost a year now and it still remains elusive as the candidate answer is shy of one vote and I am getting desperate.

While I am confident of the answer's quality, I am not sure if asking people to consider upvoting the answer (if they feel it deserves it of course) is something which is *honorable* or fair or sportsman-like behavior.

While I most certainly want the badge very much, I don't want to engage in anything which is unfair in any sense, to get it.

Can I ask people to consider my answer? Or is tooting your own horn considered gaming the system?

**EDIT:** As [Avner Shahar-Kashtan](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4516/avner-shahar-kashtan) has informed me, I was indeed [mistaken about the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood) to get a populist badge.

> rule is actually > 11
>
> and the test is > 2 * 11 on the post as well.
>
> The minimum number of votes you would need to get it, is 23.

So it appears the Populist badge is way out of my reach.

Comment: Incidentally, I couldn't find any answer of yours that seems to be a candidate. Remember, for the populist badge, the accepted answer has to have at a score of at least *11*, so yours must be at least *23* (11 * 2 + 1)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan That is what I was hoping for that the people do not find the candidate by this post. I am very well aware of the criteria. As of now, The accepted answer is at 4, My answer is at 10. To meet the eligibility criteria of >10 and x2 votes than the accepted answer, I need just one more as 4*2 = 8 and 11>10.

Comment: No, it's a commonly misunderstood criteria. The *accepted* answer has to be at >10, and yours has to be higher than twice that, so 23.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan OHHHHHHHHHH I was indeed mistaken. I was thinking that you had to outscore the accepted answer by 2x and your own answer had to be at least >10

Comment: Yeah, I've been through that as well. It's really unclear, as the various posts on meta.SE show. It's a hard badge to get.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - Well, [not that hard](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/populist?userid=20774).

Comment: You can ask to have your question/answer featured in the quarterly blog post, which promotes user suggested questions and answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Absolutely you can.

If you feel that your answer is a good 'un,  you should feel free to ask other users (in chat or comments) to upvote it.

You should, however, be aware that historically, **asking for upvotes in chat or comments has often led to downvotes being cast**, I suspect because people find it funny or simply dislike people begging for votes.

The better course of action is to do some additional research and edit your answer to "bump" it back to the top of the active page.

Comment: Besides editing to improve the answer which I always support, Aegon could bounty the question with a "Draw attention" reason. That would highlight the question for longer than an edit. I'm not sure how I'd feel about that tactic though.

Comment: @Erik - Bountying your own answer? Please downvote me. Please. Now!

Comment: You bounty the question and then award the bounty to someone else. I never said it was a perfect plan....